# Left join two tables from two different databases on two different servers with vba using an ADODB connection

Tags: text, excel, database-connection, vba

I have a database containing all orders I can connect to and query. Also, I have a text file containing the orders of the last database query I can connect to and query. I need to be able to left join the two in VBA. I don't have any problems with the database as it is in the connection string, but I can't seem to pass the text file path to the SQL string without getting and invalid object error. I am new to SQL and connecting to files. Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to do the following:

```
Sub Comp2TablesFrom2Databases()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String, strCon As String

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
strCon = "Connection string to database" 'works fine in test code that only connects to the database

strSQL = "SELECT * " _
& "FROM Database LEFT JOIN [TextFilePath] " _
& "ON Database.[Order No] = [TextFilePath].[Order No] " _
& "WHERE [TextFilePath].[Order No] IS NULL;"

rs.Open strSQL, strCon

'do stuff

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a space before `"`

Try this instead

```
strSQL = "SELECT * " _
& "FROM Database LEFT JOIN [TextFilePath] " _
& "ON Database.[Order No] = [TextFilePath].[Order No] " _
& "WHERE [TextFilePath].[Order No] IS NULL;"
```

So your query looked like:

```
SELECT * FROM Database LEFT JOIN [TextFilePath] ON Database.[Order No] = [TextFilePath].[Order No]WHERE [TextFilePath].[Order No] IS NULL;
```

So `[Order No]WHERE` should do an error

[Here's](http://www.exceluser.com/explore/msquery2_4.htm) an example of a query on a text file

I  think you should add the path

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. The lack of a space is due to me trimming down the SQL statement for posting. The real issue is that I cannot find what a SQL string should look for querying a database on one server and a text file on a local drive. Both I can query separately, but I need to be able to do a left join.

Comment: I have never done it before on a text file. How do you it separately?

Comment: Does database is the name of your table?

Comment: Using an ADODB connection, I have set up the connection string as `"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Path to folder containing text file\;Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)"";Persist Security Info=False"` and '**SELECT * FROM TextFileName.txt**'

Comment: Passing in the name of the text file to the SQL works because the connection string points to the folder. However, when trying to left join both, the connection string only points the database or the text file. I am not sure how to set up either the connection string for both or the SQL for both. Any ideas?

Comment: I should also mention that the text file is comma delimited.

Comment: Well, I would keep the connection string for the database and then write the full path for the file. Also, I would write it explicitly in the query like this Database.table.column

Comment: 1 sec, I will do a little research

Comment: Sorry, I'm not much help. Hopefully, someone else will help you

Comment: You should write this as an answer or in your question. So more people will see it.

Answer (score 0):

My quick down and dirty solution was to create an auxillary XL file which contains two sheets. One sheet queries the text file and the other queries the database. The queries are ran each time the auxillary XL file is opened. I have a left join query on the two auxillary sheets in the main XL file I want the filtered data. This is a work-around, but it works. I think the problem I ran into was that the Jet OLEDB provider doesn't support querying SQL servers and the SQL OLEDB doesn't support querying text files. If anyone knows a provider that does both I would be very appreciative.